# Repsonsive YouTube embed blocks hyperlinks above video in IOS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, youtube

I have a page with a hyperlink followed by a responsive YouTube video embed.

In the YouTube embed the 'video' element gets an inline style 'top: -342px'. This prevents the top of the hyperlink above the video from being clicked in IOS.

The problem is very similar to [an issue that occured a while back](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4569), except for the fact that the unclickable item appears above the video in this case.

Also the iframe cannot be made 'relative' because of the responsive nature of the video.

When exploring the code on an iPhone using the developer tools in Safari you can see the video element overlaying the hyperlink.

I have tried changing the stacking order but have not been succesful in solving this issue.

```css
   .content-container
        {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }

        .embed-container
        {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fermentum, nunc eget blandit imperdiet, augue turpis auctor nunc, non lacinia diam justo sit amet justo. Proin dignissim lacinia ex, eget sollicitudin sem molestie id. Proin viverra quam nisi, et mattis velit maximus vestibulum. Praesent pulvinar nibh mi, posuere aliquam odio lobortis eu. Cras eu elementum justo. Integer pellentesque eget turpis ut blandit. Suspendisse porttitor quam quis eros suscipit mollis. Nullam ultrices lacus ac cursus egestas. Vivamus non justo vitae urna interdum iaculis. Sed vel nisl vestibulum, rhoncus orci id, suscipit risus.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="embed-container"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/olFEpeMwgHk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```